# Convert Microstation dgn v8i files to shapefiles in Linux

Tags: shapefile, linux, dgn

I am looking for some program which would allow me to convert Microstation .dgn v8i files to OGR supported format (preferably ESRI shapefile) in Linux.

I have tried GRASS and QGIS, but both support only dgn version 7 or lower.